# Embedding CSS, JS, HTML into xml

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blogger

I am new to Web Development, and have done the HTML/CSS course from codecademy. Now, I am making a website for fun.

I recently heard about Bootstrap, and decide to go with that and downloaded it from the [website](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Also, I liked [this](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/stylish-portfolio/index.html) theme very much, So I am designing a new [blog on Blogger](http://htmlcssjstest.blogspot.in/).

But, in the template section, it requires to input the code in a xml file. I have the html code, css, images separately in my computer, by downloading all files from [here](http://startbootstrap.com/stylish-portfolio).

Please help me how to embed everything in one file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger xml files understand Blogger API.

For example,
CSS must be inserted between `<b:skin><![CDATA[  code here  ]]></b:skin>` tags
There are various other tags like

```
<b:section> and  <b:widget>
```

In short,the question you are referring is to How to build a blogger template.
You can google the same for numerous references.
However,I believe it may prove a lengthy exercise to learn the entire coding and would take certain amount of time to learn.So for the time being,you can search for an existing template with responsive design/bootstrap and tweak the css.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the Layout Data Tags to work with Bootstrap.
Here is the Documentation for that. https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en

Comment: Impressive ! Thanks :)